# Which is the biggest String type in SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, sqlite

Which is the biggest possible String type in SQL?

TEXT? or another?

DBMS: SQLITE and MYSQL

Comment: Depends on what DBMS you're referring to. SQL is nothing more than a *language* anyway.

Comment: @BoltClock: it doesn't depend which DBMS you're using, because all worthwhile DBMSs support CLOB, and no DBMS supports a type bigger than CLOB (excluding things like BFILE, which is not really a string type).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The largest character data type in **MySql** is `LONGTEXT` (see [Storage Requirements for String Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html)), that is capable to hold 2^32-1 bytes.

**SQLite** does not impose any length restrictions (other than the large global SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH limit) on the length of strings, BLOBs or numeric values. The default limit for that is 1 billion, but you can change it at compile time to a maximum of 2^31-1 (see [Maximum length of a string or BLOB](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_length)).

Comment: then, a TEXT type in SQLite can store the same as a LONGTEXT type of MYSQL ?

Comment: MySql can store the double amount: 2^32 vs. 2^31.

Comment: So SQLite *doesn't* support CLOB, but has a varchar that is as big as most CLOBs!

Comment: @AndroidUser99: Please read the section "Affinity Name Examples" from the following link: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html. You can use any of the given TEXT affinity data types and you will get maximum string length, as there is just the already mentioned limit for all of them, regardless what you specify as column length. (At least that's my understanding of that section.)

Answer (score 2):

CLOB.

The SQL standard uses the name CLOB (it's feature T041-02 in SQL2008), but note that other databases may have different names for it. I think TEXT is one.

Comment: Googling "mysql clob type" brought up "Longtext" for mysql.